# Conditionally render a class to a grid cell, then remove it on a state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, conditional-rendering

Ok, so first time question-asker here, but I'm having trouble rendering a class to a grid cell, then removing it. The idea is the grid is the floor, and the class represents a roomba moving around it. I want to render the roomba where the cell id matches the position saved in state. Here's my code for the grid component:

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Grid(props) {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(props.location);
  const [roomba, setRoomba] = useState({
    location: "1, 1",
  });
  const theRoomba = `${position[0]}, ${position[1]}`;
  const renderRoomba = document.getElementById(theRoomba);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomba) {
      setPosition(props.location);
      setRoomba(position);
      console.log("Im the current location", props.location);
    }
  }, [props.location]);

  const grid = [];
  for (let i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (let j = 10; j >= 1; j--) {
      grid.push(
        <div className="square" id={`${i}, ${j}`} key={`${i}, ${j}`}>
          {`${i}, ${j}`}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const updatedGrid = [];
  grid.map((cell) => {
    if (renderRoomba) {
      renderRoomba.classList.add("roomba");
      updatedGrid.push(cell);
    } else {
      updatedGrid.push(cell);
    }
    return updatedGrid;
  });
  return <div className="grid">{updatedGrid}</div>;
}

export default Grid;
```

---

I'm a bit of a noob and know this is probably bloated, but it currently renders my 10x10 grid, and I can move my roomba around but can't ever remove the className='roomba' from the previous cell. I've tried a few DOM manipulation methods but nothing seems very 'React-ty'. Appreciate any help/feedback, this has been wracking my brain all week!

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this? Or at the very least explain what `props.location` is and/or how the parent component declares this component?

Comment: I have an App component as the parent for Grid, passing it down a state property called location, initialized at [1, 1]. I have buttons for directions in a separate component with the state 'direction' that also take location prop from App. Also a component called Location in App that tracks props.location and updates as expected. So the effect I'm getting is a like a snake game when a new direction is input, instead of  roomba appearing to traverse the grid cell-by-cell. Hope that helps, I can post more code I just didn't want to go nuts with it lol ty for the response btw!

Comment: Generally, the more code provided the more specific an answer can be! If you're worried about it, I'd recommend creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) and linking to it with all of your code. Going off of that, it's still hard to give you a definitive answer as to what's wrong but my guess is that you need to call `renderRoomba.classList.remove("roomba")` on the `renderRoomba` element somewhere before executing a "traverse".

Comment: Wow ty so much, I never even thought of that! Here's the codesandbox with everything as it currently functions: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-river-qw3k0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Looks like you might not have saved your changes? All of the components in the `components` directory are empty.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-river-qw3k0?file=/src/App.css&fbclid=IwAR3V3k7WLJfBYxDyvc0vrVzYDdln4qRA4SHD4hFkvJTYQwj5vfE3VKa5XoI 
hopefully this one works!